# jquery - define that a loading effect only appear ONCE

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click on a certain icon, I add to the DOM a loading message. The problem is that if the user clicks twice (while the final message is loading, he sees this message twice....).

How to only prevent the appearance of a second "loading..." per screen ? I never want more than one at once.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
    //show loading message
    $("#icon1, #icon2, #icon3").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("Loading ...")
      .insertAfter( $( "#icon1" ) );
    });    
  });
```

Note: some users suggested to use .one: I don't think it works because it means I can only click once then nothiung happens. It is not what I want to do. i want that WHILE a user sees "loading..", he can"t sees another "loading..." but he can still click onc,e sees the "loading...", then when the "loading.." disappears he can click and see it appear again.

Comment: Check if element is already added by using `if( $('#icon1').length)` and if this  is zero, then only add it.

Comment: a simple if would do the trick!

Comment: Use `.one()` instead of `click()`

Comment: instead of `.on` use `.one` with eact same syntax

Comment: trying Tushar recommendation but for the other comments on ./one see my NOTE at the end of the question, it doesn't meet my needs (i think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable, and check if it is true or false

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
    //show loading message
    var isLoading = false;
    $("#icon1, #icon2, #icon3").click(function(e) {
      if(isLoading == true) return;
      isLoading = true;
      e.preventDefault();
      $("Loading ...")
      .insertAfter( $( "#icon1" ) );

     //After finishing loading
     isLoading = false;
    });    
  });
```